# How can I make the ticks stop for a certain amount of time in the Giant Component model?

Tags: netlogo

While exploring the Giant Component model, i was looking for an option to stop the ticks for a certain time after they've reached a specific fraction size (looking for 0.5). Is there any way I could import some type of pause to be able to check the connection per node at 0.5 fraction size?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the model to stop at a certain point to allow you to inspect things, and then continue executing. Let's assume that you can identify the stopping condition in the `go` procedure. Issuing the `stop` command will "lift" the go button, whereupon you can look at whatever you like. When you press the go button again, the model will resume.  Here is some sample code.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  ask turtles [forward 10]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [forward 1]
  wait 1
  tick
  if (ticks mod 10) = 0 [stop]
end
```